# Flatten fails to return any data in CoGroupByKey

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am currently using apache beam 2.4. My pipeline includes a CoGroupByKey step which does not return any data.
As I expand the task in the UI, the data does not flow beyond the internal Flatten.PCollection of CoGroupByKey.

My code is structured as presented in the [javadoc](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/join/CoGroupByKey.html)  example

```
static final TupleTag<String> simpleEventTag1 = new TupleTag<String>(){};
static final TupleTag<String> simpleEventTag2 = new TupleTag<String>(){};
PCollection<KV<String, String>> pt1 = ...;
PCollection<KV<String, String>> pt2 = ...;

 PCollection<KV<String, CoGbkResult>> coGbkResultCollection =
   KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(simpleEventTag1, pt1)
                        .and(simpleEventTag2, pt2)
                        .apply(CoGroupByKey.create());
```

My window is:

```
Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
    .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime
    .pastFirstElementInPane()
    .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(20))
    )
)
.withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
.discardingFiredPanes()
```

pt1 and pt2 are both retrieved from a PCollectionTuple and are not empty. They share the same FixedWindow properties.
I don't know what I am doing wrong and could not find any way to debug this issue. Any idea ?

[Expanded CoGroupBy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byIq7.png)

Comment: How large is your fixed window? The data will only flow past the internal `Flatten.PCollection` after the watermark has passed the end of the window (assuming you're using default triggers).

Comment: Is there any other step following the `CoGroupByKey`? If not, you'll need to add a sink (can be just writing a finish message to Pub/Sub, for example) at the end of the pipeline to trigger execution of all the intermediate steps when using DataflowRunner

Comment: Yes there are extra steps, I am using the CoGbkResult in an extra DoFn before finally sinking the output data in a PubSub Topic.

Comment: @onairos Does your extra DoFn drop any cogrouped results with null values? If so, it is likely that cogrouped results are dropped because of current aggressive windowing and triggers.

Comment: No, for each key I extract my two sub PCollections and apply specific logic before pushing the output into a String topic. I imported apache beam CoGroupBy java file in my module and try to debug/add logging from there.

Comment: Hi @onairos, were you able to resolve this?